# VBA Copy split elements of vertically saved strings to another sheet in horizontal manner

Tags: string, vba, copy

I am looking to save the vertically saved Information for each ID (row 1) from this Worksheet:

[image]

To another Worksheet, which Looks like this:

[image]

For each column, with the ID in row 1, there are skills saved as strings. Each part (there are 3) is supposed to be saved on the second Worksheet in column B,C and D, respectively.

With the code I will post below, there is no Error. It simply doesn't do anything. When using a stop in the code, the problem seems to be that the items ID's I am trying to find (FindIDcol, FindIDrow) are simply "Nothing".

I am very new to VBA and might have a way too complicated Approach or ineffective code. However, I hope one of you can help me out here.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Here my code:

```
Dim wsInput As Worksheet
Set wsInput = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Supplier Skills")
Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
Set wsOutput = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Search Skills")

Dim IDcolumn As Range
Dim IDrow As Range
Dim lastcol As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim NextRow As Integer
Dim FindIDcol As Range
Dim FindIDrow As Range

With wsInput
    lastcol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastColLetter = Split(Cells(1, lastcol).Address(True, False), "$")(0)

    'For every column on Input-Sheet with Data
    For Each IDcolumn In wsInput.Range("A1:" & LastColLetter & "1")

        'Firstly, find each ID column
        FindIDcol = wsInput.Range("A1:" & LastColLetter & "1").Find(What:=IDcolumn, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not FindIDcol Is Nothing Then

            'Secondly, get the respective column Letter
            IDcolLetter = Split(FindIDcol.Address, "$")(0)

                'Thirdly, find all skills saved in rows beneath this column
                lastRow = .Range(IDcolLetter & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
                For Each IDrow In wsInput.Range(IDcolLetter & "1:" & IDcolLetter & lastRow)

                    'Fourthly, get the respective row-number for each skill
                    FindIDrow = wsInput.Range(IDcolLetter & "2:" & IDcolLetter & lastRow).Find(What:=IDrow, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
                    IDrowNumber = Split(FindIDrow.Address, "$")(1)

                    'Fifthly, split the strings in 3 parts
                    Dim myElements() As String
                    myElements = Split(wsInput.Range(IDcolLetter & IDrowNumber).value, "\")

                    'Sixthly, for every skill of that supplier, copy the ID in A, CG in B, Category in C and Product in D
                    NextRow = wsOutput.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1

                    wsInput.Range(IDcolLetter & "1").Copy Destination:=wsOutput.Range("A" & NextRow) 'ID
                    wsOutput.Range("B" & NextRow) = myElements(0)                                 'Commodity Group
                    wsOutput.Range("C" & NextRow) = myElements(1)                                 'Category
                    wsOutput.Range("D" & NextRow) = myElements(2)                                 'Product

                Next IDrow

        End If

    Next IDcolumn

End With
```

Comment: It should be `Set FindIDcol = ...`. That should give you an error message though. That said, wouldn't `FindIFcol`and `IDcol` be the same (unless there are duplicate IDs)?

Comment: IDcolumn has always shown the value of the cell, so the ID. Which meant I was working with. i.e. "A300743" for the first ID. That's why I started using the IDcolLetter and IDrowNumber with splitting the Address. I will try the Set. Thank you already!

Comment: Your tip, together with two changes in the Splitting made it work! :) If you write your comment as a seperate answer, I will be able to upvote you.

Comment: My point was that you take the ID (actually the cell that contains the ID) from the first row, then you search for the ID in the first row, what's the point of that?

Comment: You don't need the column letters. You can set ranges using the first and last cell, so `.Range(.Cells(1, 1),  .Cells(1, lastcol))`. Also use `Option Explicit` to prevent typos.

Comment: Because I did not know any other way to get the cell address, so that I can split it later. The first time I take the ID cell, it is just to define a range.

Comment: But `IDcolumn` is a (single cell) range and then `FindIDcol` will be the exact same cell so why not just use `IDcolumn`?

Comment: Aaah, now I get what you mean. Indeed, I deleted These two doublings and am now directly referring to IDcolumn and IDrow and it still works. Thank you for your effort! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

standing your shown data *structure* and if I correctly interpreted your goal, you can simplify your code as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim colCell As Range, rowCell As Range
    Dim outputRow As Long

    Set wsOutput = Worksheets("Output") '<--| change "Output" to your actual output sheet name
    outputRow = 2 '<--| initialize output row to 2 (row 1 is for headers)

    With Worksheets("Input") '<--| reference input sheet (change "Input" to your actual input sheet name)
        For Each colCell In .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| iterate over its row 1 non blank cells
            For Each rowCell In .Range(colCell.Offset(1), colCell.End(xlDown)) '<--| iterate over current column rows from row 2 down to last contiguous non empty one
                wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, 1) = colCell.Value '<--| write ID in column 1 of current output row
                wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, 2).Resize(, 3) = Split(rowCell.Value, "\") '<--| write other info from column 2 rightwards of current output row
                outputRow = outputRow + 1 '<--| update output row
            Next rowCell
        Next colCell
    End With
End Sub
```

should you deal with input sheet non contiguous data below any ID (blank cells) or ID with no data below, there would be needed a few changes